# What happened to the Users page?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

The users page https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users is now really really ugly. What happened there? Can it be reverted?

Comment: Closing. Problem being discussed on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-users-page/

Answer (score 3):

It is not a bug.  [The users page has been redesigned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80690/redesigning-the-users-page).  Naturally, someone has already [raised an issue with the new design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81131/the-new-user-page-layout-requires-some-work) on Meta Stack Overflow.

*Added*: Some other issues have been raised: see the [questions on Meta Stack Overflow with the [users-page] tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users-page).

Comment: Ah. It's a feature! I guess this question should be closed then, if it's something happening at levels higher up.

Comment: It's a very strange feature, if you check the /users page right now (the beginning of a new week)...

Comment: @Jukka: That is discussed here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81096/week-is-not-a-useful-default-for-the-users-page